# Calling window.webkitRequestFileSystem twice causes first call not to be bypassed

Tags: html, file, cordova, blackberry-10

Have an interesting problem ... I am making a BB10 application (I know) and am using the window.webkitRequestFileSystem call to a) provide a list of local files that this application has downloaded and b) read one of those files and display the contents - nothing crazy.

Individually, I can get both calls a) and b) to work; however, when I place them in the same function hoping to both display a list of files and read one of them, it causes the reading one not to fire *at all*.

In the example below, regardless of whether the listing call comes before or after the reading call, the reading call will not fire, i.e., I will never see the 'fileentry' alert.

What's going on?

```
function initFS(){
sharedFolder = blackberry.io.sharedFolder;

var path = sharedFolder+'/downloads';
//alert(path);

document.getElementById('plancontents').value="initialized";

window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || 
window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

//window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024,
//window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024*5,
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024*5,
function (fs) {
    //fs.root.getFile(blackberry.io.sharedFolder 
    //fs.root.getFile('file:///accounts/1000/shared/downloads/filename.xml', {create: false},
    fs.root.getFile(sharedFolder+'/downloads/filename.xml', {create: false},
    function (fileEntry) {
        alert("fileentry");
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            //alert("trying to read file");
            reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                document.getElementById('plancontents').value = this.result;
            };

            reader.readAsText(file);
        }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
});

window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024*5,
function (fs) {
    alert('FS requested and inside');

    fs.root.getDirectory(path, {}, function(dirEntry){
        alert('inside getDir');

        var dirReader = dirEntry.createReader();

        alert('created reader');

        dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
            alert('trying to list dir');

            for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                var entry = entries[i];

                if (entry.isDirectory) {
                    alert('Directory: ' + entry.fullPath);
                }
                else if (entry.isFile) {
                    alert('File: ' + entry.fullPath);
                }
            }
        }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
});
```

}